# How do I dive down multiple levels in Beautiful Soup (find_all error)

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to drill down two levels in this Python script.  All the examples I see drill down a single level using find_all, and I can get that working fine, but I'm not able to get down to the third level.  Here is my code snippet:

```
main_table = soup.find("div",attrs={'class':'block-content'})
label_item_contents = main_table.find_all("div", attrs={'class':'label-item-description'})
links = label_item_contents.find_all("a")
print(links)
```

Doing this gives me the error "AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find_all'."

If I comment out and change the print so it's this:

```
main_table = soup.find("div",attrs={'class':'block-content'})
label_item_contents = main_table.find_all("div", attrs={'class':'label-item-description'})
print(label_item_contents)
```

Then I see all the scraped data.  I read that the issue could be that label_item_contents becomes an array, so I tried to do this:

```
links = label_item_contents[].find_all("a")
```

But then I get "SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

Any help is appreciated!

EDIT:  Here is a portion of the HTML that is returned in the second example when I use print(label_item_contents):

```
<div class="label-item-description">
    <div>
        <a href="/label/example.com"><strong>Example</strong></a>
    </div>
    <small>
        <i class="fa fa-facebook-official"></i> 342.4K
        <i class="fa fa-soundcloud"></i> 233.4K
    </small>
    <br />
    <small class="text-muted">
        Stockholm, Sweden
    </small>
    <br />
    <small class="text-muted">
        <b>Techno, Tech House</b>
    </small>
</div>, <div class="label-item-description">
```

I am trying to only get to `<a href="/label/example.com">`

Comment: post your html so we can have an idea

Comment: @SebastienD the resulting html when I use print(label_item_contents)?

Comment: well, the html you used for your soup variable ie : `soup=BeautifulSoup(html)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may want to give the CSS selectors a try -- I found them to be more familiar and importantly, I found them to cause fewer `AttributeError` problems.

For example, using the above `html` you can select the first anchor tag like this:

```
link = soup.select("div.label-item-description > div > a")
print(link[0]) # <a href="/label/example.com"><strong>Example</strong></a>
```

See the docs:

https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors

Comment: Well that seemed to work perfectly-and got rid of about half of my code!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Two other alternative you might be able to use:

```
links = [item['href'] for item in soup.select('.label-item-description a')]
links2 = [item['href'] for item in soup.select('.label-item-description [href^="/label/"]')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's right but why not doing so? You can chain `find`to get to the desired sub div:

```
html= """
<div class="block-content">
    <div class="label-item-description">
        <div>
            <a href="/label/example.com"><strong>Example</strong></a>
        </div>
        <small>
            <i class="fa fa-facebook-official"></i> 342.4K
            <i class="fa fa-soundcloud"></i> 233.4K
        </small>
        <br />
        <small class="text-muted">
            Stockholm, Sweden
        </small>
        <br />
        <small class="text-muted">
            <b>Techno, Tech House</b>
        </small>
    </div>, <div class="label-item-description"></div>
</div>  """

soup=BeautifulSoup(html)
print(soup.find('div', {'class': 'block-content'}).find('div',  {'class':"label-item-description"}).find('a'))
```

output:

```
<a href="/label/example.com"><strong>Example</strong></a>
```

Comment: There are lots of other <a> throughout the whole page.  The specific one I need is within <div class="block-content"><div class="label-item-description"><a href "this one"></a></div></div>

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes we use anchor tag but it does not contain `href` attribute.

You can try `find_all` function, it always returns a list and use `href=True` attribute with anchor tag will give you all links which has a `href` attribute.

```
main_table = soup.find("div",{'class':'label-item-description'})
links = main_table.find_all("a",href=True)
print(links)
```